# NHibernate - truly dynamic sorting

Tags: nhibernate, sql-order-by

Using NHibernate, I need to be able to configure my application to sort a specific collection of entities exactly as needed.

The configurable sort:

- can involve multiple properties
- can specify the sorted properties in any order
- can specify asc/desc on the sorted properties
- can sort by custom properties (i.e. there is no corresponding SQL/C# property - it is calculated)

This functionality is inherited from an existing app where parts of the SQL are specified by an administrator and the SQL statement is built/executed dynamically.

Every time I try thinking through a solution I start getting in muddy waters with all kinds of alarms going off in my head regarding maintainability, performance, scalability, security, etc..

For example, I figure the admin can specify a comma delimited string like so:

"Date asc, FirstName asc, LastName desc"

I can split the string and go through a loop matching the property/sort pairings in a case statement and calling .AddOrder(Order.Asc("FirstName")) as necessary.  But then, how do I handle custom properties?  I could allow the user to specify SQL for calculating custom properties and then allow the user to sort on those like they would FirstName, but I'm seemingly back at dirty/kludge again.

Is there a clean/appropriate way to handle this requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much thought and a stroke of luck, I may have a solution.

```
public class CustomOrder : Order
{
  private string customOrderSql;

  public CustomOrder(string customOrderSql) : base("", true)
  {
    this.customOrderSql = customOrderSql;
  }

public override NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString ToSqlString(
    ICriteria criteria, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) 
  { 
    return new NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString(this.customOrderSql); 
  }

}
```

I can pass a custom sort string to my repository where I add my CustomOrder as follows:

```
.AddOrder(new CustomOrder(customSort))
```

I still can't sort by custom properties but maybe I can get away with applying case statements in the order by clause.  I'm still open for better suggestions if they exist.

Comment: You are actually just taking the users input as SQL. But you could parse (eg. for custom properties), validate and build SQL from scratch it in your CustomOrder class. In my opinion, it is a pretty good start.